# Azure Active Directory B2C, 404 error, unexpected question mark in URL

Tags: azure, active-directory, http-status-code-404, azure-ad-b2c

I am implementing Azure Active Directory B2C from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi) official tutorial.
when I run my code it says
`404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`
The issue is with URL, it contain question mark ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGQLf.jpg)). In place of question mark there should me an ampersand (&), if I manually replace "?" with "&" it works fine.
Here my startup class

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        // App config settings
        public static string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        public static string ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        public static string AadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
        public static string Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
        public static string RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
        public static string ServiceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:TaskServiceUrl"];

    // B2C policy identifiers
    public static string SignUpSignInPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId"];
    public static string EditProfilePolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:EditProfilePolicyId"];
    public static string ResetPasswordPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId"];

    public static string DefaultPolicy = SignUpSignInPolicyId;

    // API Scopes
    public static string ApiIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ApiIdentifier"];
    public static string ReadTasksScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ReadScope"];
    public static string WriteTasksScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:WriteScope"];
    public static string[] Scopes = new string[] { ReadTasksScope, WriteTasksScope };

    // OWIN auth middleware constants
    public const string ObjectIdElement = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";

    // Authorities
    public static string Authority = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy);

    // Initialize variables ...

    // Configure the OWIN middleware
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
            // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
            MetadataAddress = Authority,

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = ClientId,
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,

            // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },

            // Specify the claims to validate
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                },

            // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (seperated by a blank space)
            Scope = $"{OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId} {ReadTasksScope} {WriteTasksScope}"
            }
        );
    }`
```

and here webconfig

```
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="explicarte.onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="a2d**********************" />
<add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="0f**************" />
<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}" />
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://explicarted.azurewebsites.net/" />
<add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_MySignupSigninPolicy" />
<add key="EditProfilePolicyId" value="B2C_1_myProfileEditingPolicy" />
<add key="ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="B2C_1_PasswordResetPolicy" />
<add key="api:ApiIdentifier" value="https://explicarted.azurewebsites.net/tasks/" />
<add key="api:ReadScope" value="read" />
<add key="api:WriteScope" value="write" />
<add key="api:TaskServiceUrl" value="https://explicarted.azurewebsites.net/" />
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you have already added "?" mark to ida:AadInstance url. Library code doesn't scan url, just appends parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue around handling pre-existing query string parameters in one of the .Net libraries.

You are most likely using one of these older versions. I believe the specific problematic library is [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions).

You should try updating this library or just taking the sample as a starting point as that one already has correct (updated) libraries.

PS: You should use the following authority:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/**tfp**/{0}/**{1}**/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration